# как правильно настроить часовой пояс на сервере (докер или обычный)и каждого user? laravel

Tags: laravel

К примеру, на сервере сейчас 20-00, а у юзера 19-00.

И даётся пользователю токен на 10 мин, то есть, 19-10 -  время истечения, в таком случае он автоматически истёк.

А у другого юзера -  23-00.

Получается, истечет токен только через 3 часа, а должен через 10 минут.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что это так работает? Я не уверен, но думаю, что метка времени передаётся либо в UTC, либо с указанием часового пояса

Comment: на локалке регистрируюсь время в БД отличается от времени на компе

Comment: Изменить часовой пояс приложения можно в `config/app.php`. Например: `'timezone' => 'Europe/Moscow'`

Comment: Насчёт токена не до конца понял вопрос. Какой токен вы имеете в виду? Вы как-то самостоятельно создаёте его?

Comment: токен авторизации да это для Rest Api

Comment: Так токен должен создаваться от времени на сервере. Если у другого юзера 23 то на сервере всё равно 20 часов вечера. метод date(...) будет всегда возвращать серверное время.

Comment: @DmitriiSedov Sedov
точно спасибо